# "nasm" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c++, cmake, nasm

I am trying to compile [libjpeg-turbo library](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo) using windows cmake. I am trying to follow the instrcutions found in that lib in order to compile the lib. I am operning a Visual studio terminal and I give in the first step the path of the library. My commands are the following:

```
cd ..path
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
nmake
```

The first command worked fine I am getting the message build files have been writer to path. However when I am trying to run nmake command I am getting errors:

> "nasm" is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Any idea about what is nasm and how can I import it to my path.

Comment: Nasm is an assembler. See http://www.nasm.us/

Comment: You will need to install NASM onto your system. Appears at a minimum you'll need 2.11.08 according to the libjpeg information. You can download the 2.11.08 Windows installer from here: http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.11.08/win32/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the problem you reported, it looks to me that the issue could be because of the PATH variable or configuration settings. The problem you reported have similar posts please refer to following links:

1. http://sourceforge.net/p/libjpeg-turbo/bugs/24/
2. https://github.com/Zeex/sampgdk/issues/42

Also it would be great if you could post the crash log or build process output from the console to further investigate the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks I found it, thanks for the help. One little question, how can I compile it as a static library??

Comment: During the build process a dll and a lib file have been created. Is the dll file corresponds to dynamic library and lib file to static library? Or in order to create the static library I have to do something else.

Comment: Never done it @JoseRamon. From top of my head the dll files should be manipulated to build as static. Since they generally corresponds to "run time" configurations. But please do update the post if you find a way to do it.